# Visual Studio Gallery - MVC Project Template Failing to Upload

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template, vsix

I've created a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET MVC Project Template as a VSIX package that I'd like to upload to the Visual Studio Gallery, but every time I try it tells me the path is too long...

Locally, it installs and works without issue...

The structure of the project (zipped as t.zip to try and reduce the length) is a standard MVC structured project, the only caveat is that it needs (well, doesn't need to but makes sense for it be there) installs to the Web sub-folder under the C# language, so the path inside the VSIX package is `ProjectTemplate\CSharp\Web`.

Is there a way around this limitation, or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a check when you upload to the VS Gallery to see if the path length might end up being too long when installed on the users machine. This check includes not only the files directly in your VSIX, but also the files embedded inside the zip file. (This is because templates are unzipped on disk before they are used for instantiating a new project.)

Unfortunately, I think your only option is to shorten-up the paths of the files in the template itself.